# Redirecting Content from Blog to Website Drawbacks

Tags: ruby, redirect, blogs, content-model

What are the drawbacks of using the content/data model of a blog like Blogger or Wordpress to store all of your information and then just having it redirect you to your "real" website?  I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to setup a blog and just read/write from it but render it in a completely different project, so I don't have to recreate the blog model objects (user/category/post/comment, etc.).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is anything wrong with it really, you just have to be careful with search engines. Many of them will ban your site if it redirects, and also it will show up as duplicate content (your website and the blog) and most search engines don't like that.

But if you don't care about search engine results there shouldn't be any real downsides to doing what you're doing.